# Application architecture nodejs ("server.create" is not a function)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an error "server.create" is not a function when i start my nodejs application.

My code :

index.js (file to start)

```
server.create(configuration);
server.start();
```

server.js

```
module.exports = function() {
let server = express(), create, start;

create = function(configuration) {
    let routes = require('./routes/index');

    server.set('env', configuration.env);
    server.set('port', configuration.port);
    server.set('hostname', configuration.hostname);

    server.use("/post/recrutement", formidable({
        encoding       : 'utf-8',
        uploadDir      : 'uploads',
        multiples      : false,
        keepExtensions : true
    }));

    server.use("/post/newsletter", bodyparser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
    server.use("/post/newsletter", bodyparser.json());

    server.use("/post/contact", bodyparser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
    server.use("/post/contact", bodyparser.json());

    routes.init(server);
};

start = function() {
    let hostname = server.get('hostname'), port = server.get('port');

    server.listen(port, function() {
        console.log('Server started on - http://' + hostname + ':' + port);
    });
};

return  {
    create : create,
    start  : start
};
```

};

if you have an idea to solve my problem it will be a great help.

Thank you

Comment: there is no `x` defined in your code as a function ... so, that is correct, `x` is not a function - does the error *really* say `x` is not a function, or is `x` in your question a replacement for the *real* error?

Comment: in which line its failed

Comment: @bravo Yeah i know my error is "server.create is not a function"

Comment: I see ... because you export a function, but never call it, it's the result of calling the function that returns `.create` and `.start` - how are you importing/requiring server.js? `const server = require("./server.js")`? You could do `const server = require("./server.js")();` but that looks awkward (though it would work) - you should export differently :p

Comment: @Bravo Yeah i importing the function via `const server = require("./app/server");`

Comment: so, as a test ... `const server = require("./app/server")();` - does it work better now? - I'd still look at rewriting server.js though - drop the `module.exports = funciton() {` ... and then `module.exports = { create, start };`

Comment: @Bravo Nice It works ! yeah i think i will rewrite server.js